# Python use re.sub to search for string and change from dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, subprocess

I have an python script where I read an csv file and on one column in the csv file I want to search and replace from an dictionary.
My code works if I have 100% matching fields both in csv and the dictionary.
My problem is that in the dictionary the field which holds the matching string from csv can be inside long string separated by comma, so I want to search in the dictionary string and on any partial match I want to change out the value from dictionary.
As example from code beneath the newdata looks like this:

```
u'46764967051,46490797539,4639238933': u'google.com', u'46104376787335,46739600111': u'bt.se', u'46700961026,4638138399': u'lake.se'
```

And my csv field 2 is where I have the number with which I want to do the re.sub on.
Lets say I have the number in that csv field: 4638138399
In that case I want to searach for that in the dictionary (newdata) and change to the domain in this example "lake.se" as that number is in the last dictionary (newdata).
So my question what can i change on the row

```
domain = re.sub(domain, lambda find_all: newdata.get(find_all.group(0), domain), domain)
```

To make it search for any match and not only full match?

My code:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://ip-addr:27017/user')
db = client['user']

x   = []
cur = db.user.find()
for i in cur:
    x.append(i)

newdata = {}    
for entry in x:
    numbers = entry.pop('numbers')
    numbers = numbers.replace("+","")
    domain = entry.pop('domain')
    newdata[numbers] = domain

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
# csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                        dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
for row in csv_reader:
    # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
    yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')


reader = unicode_csv_reader(codecs.open("201807_12_49333_N29069.csv", 
encoding="iso-8859-1"))
for row in reader:
    domain = row[2].encode('ascii') 
    domain = str(domain)
    domain = re.sub(domain, lambda find_all: newdata.get(find_all.group(0), domain), domain)
    row[2] = domain
    print(row[2], row[3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to rejigger `newdata` so that instead of each of its keys consisting of multiple comma-separated numbers, it has a different key for each number. This makes sense because dictionary entries are most easily looked up by their exact keys, as opposed to substrings of keys. Just replace the line `newdata[numbers] = domain` with `for n in numbers.split(','): newdata[n] = domain`. Here's a self-contained example:

```
import re

x = [
    dict(numbers = u'46764967051,46490797539,4639238933',
        domain = u'google.com'),
    dict(numbers = u'46104376787335,46739600111',
        domain = u'bt.se'),
    dict(numbers = u'46700961026,4638138399',
        domain = u'lake.se')]
newdata = {}
for entry in x:
    numbers = entry.pop('numbers')
    numbers = numbers.replace("+","")
    domain = entry.pop('domain')
    for n in numbers.split(','):
        newdata[n] = domain

s = "my favorite site is 46490797539"
s = re.sub(r"\d+", lambda m: newdata[m.group(0)], s)
print(s)
```